# Docker-compose Extends Option and Relative Paths

Tags: docker

I try to call a docker-compose from another docker-compose using the extends option.  However, it seems to not work properly with the relative paths.  The error below is what I get.

```
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
../../Interfaces/Proto/Sync/1.0 : warning : directory does not exist. [/src/SyncServer/SyncServer.csproj]
Could not make proto path relative : error : ../../Interfaces/Proto/Sync/1.0/greet.proto: No such file or directory [/src/SyncServer/SyncServer.csproj]

Build FAILED.

../../Interfaces/Proto/Sync/1.0 : warning : directory does not exist. [/src/SyncServer/SyncServer.csproj]
Could not make proto path relative : error : ../../Interfaces/Proto/Sync/1.0/greet.proto: No such file or directory [/src/SyncServer/SyncServer.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.59
ERROR: Service 'syncserver_mgr' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet build "SyncServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The part of the calling docker-compose that extends another docker compose.

```
  syncserver_mgr:
     extends:
         file: C:\QNMS\Sync\docker-compose-sync-without-network-def.yml
         service: syncserver
```

called docker-compose file (docker-compose-sync-without-network-def.yml)

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  syncserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}syncserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SyncServer/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - syncNetwork
```

Called Dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SyncServer/SyncServer.csproj", "SyncServer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SyncServer/SyncServer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SyncServer"
RUN dotnet build "SyncServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SyncServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SyncServer.dll"]

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping
```

Comment: The `extends` keywords [has been deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services)  quite some time ago. You should consider [using multiple compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compose file you are extending is version `3.x`. The `extends` keyword is only supported [up to version 2.1](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understand-the-extends-configuration). The two files need to be the same major version at the least. If you want using `3.4` features specifically, both files need be version `3.4`, for example.